# Should I load images in the home screen again from API or initially save it to device for a Unity based AR app?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

When the app starts,API calls are made and JSON is converterd into string.Using image URLs I convert them into textures and set them as raw images.Below is how my home screen looks like.

[image: AppFlow]

When I click a cell in the home screen it takes me away to product details screen.In that I click AR button which takes me to a **new scene** where I Place the AR content on real world.The problem is that when I open a ARscene all the data in the old scene is deleted. ie When I hit back button from AR scene to Product detail scene Images and product details are null.For this problem I have saved them to player prefs and images on to  Application.persistentDataPath and later loads it when I hit back from the AR scene.

After opening the AR scene, when I navigate back to home screen I am reloading the scene similar to how app opens. Is it good to load the images from API when I reach back to the home screen or Initially load them to Application.persistentDatapath and load the images from there.What should I do with the Home screen?

```
IEnumerator GetAllTextures(int m ,int n)
{


        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(150, 150, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
    string url = JNode[m]["product_images"][n];



        WWW imgurllinks = new WWW(url);
        yield return imgurllinks;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgurllinks.error))
        {
            yield return null;

        }

        imgurllinks.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
        Allassetimageurl.Add(new Imagesinfo(assetiid[m], JNode[m]["product_images"][n],tex));


}



IEnumerator FillData()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < assetimageurl.Count; i++)
    {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(150,150, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);


        WWW imgurllinks = new WWW(assetimageurl[i]);
        yield return imgurllinks;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgurllinks.error))
        {
            yield return null;

        }

        imgurllinks.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
        rimg.texture = tex;

        TextureList.Add(tex);

        Productxt.text = productname[i];
        Pricetxt.text = "$" +assetpriceurl[i].ToString();


        var go=  Instantiate(Mainprefab, ParentTransform) as GameObject;



        GO.Add(go);


    }



}
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you want to cache the images/textures. then it all depends on how often an image changes and the impact of showing an older image. It would be nice if the returned url's had some extra information like a version number or last changed.

Comment: @Dexter But if I cache them will it be gone when I change my scene?

Comment: I really don't know anything about scene. I just stated that if you are caching (saving to  Application.persistentDatapath) you should consider usage of old images. Then you have extra information, you at least know when to refresh the images in your  Application.persistentDatapath. Then it works just fine, and i would prefer it over downloading the image again.

Comment: I have used image loading and caching in Unity before. If you want to preserve them, try storing the path you are saving them to in your PlayerPrefs. Then when you (re)load the scene, do a lookup using the stored path in playerprefs. if there is no path or if the validity expired, get it from the database.

Comment: How to create a cache folder in IOS app? After closure of app will delete it its contents?Should I make something like that in the Application.persistentDatapath ?